# Swashbuckle global filter instead of individual attributes

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` (4.0.1), and `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters` (4.5.5) for request/response examples.

Instead of applying an `[Authorization]` attribute to every action, I want to do that automatically. There is [some code](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#operation-filters) in the readme that shows how to do this.

This is the key line:

```
operation.Responses.Add("401", new Response { Description = "Unauthorized" });
```

But that adds very little metadata.

What I'm currently doing is this:

```
[SwaggerResponse(401, "Invalid credentials", typeof(Response401))]
[SwaggerResponseExample(401, typeof(Response401Example))]
```

There is a lot more data in there. How do I do the same using the global filter?

Comment: Can you add some info on how you would like the final json spec to look like?

Comment: That code you link to is using an IOperationFilter, IF that is what you want to do, look into combining that with what is done in SwaggerResponseExample: 
https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters/blob/01abd935ac427490d3b8185ebfb0fb56f4076664/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters/Examples/ExamplesOperationFilter.cs

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Thanks I'll look into that